# How do you flag/upvote comments on election material?

Tags: support, election

I'd think you couldn't but there is an upvoted comment by @Emrakul on @WaxEagle's nomination post.  Is there a place other than the nomination screen where you're supposed to look at these?  Will it work the same way for the election phase?

Comment: Comment in question appears to be [the second one on Wax Eagle's nomination](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-59200).

Comment: Also: being able to upvote things more easily would be good and help prevent, for example, the "me too" comments.  Unless my perception of the situation here is lacking a large amount of site functionality, which is quite possible.  It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: I thought you could before too, but I can't see how now. Maybe it's because the nominations phase is about to close? Not sure why extra effort would be made to code such a cutoff, though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I took me nearly a week to post this.  I am slow cause I research for a long time before posting anything on meta ^^;  That is very definitely not the explanation.

Comment: Then I am indeed baffled by that little "1" there!

Comment: An SO election is going on simultaneous to ours, there may have been some mild changes to the election engine because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug, and was disabled when it was caught during the SO election that is being held concurrently with ours. See this for more information:

[Can *too* upvote comments under an election nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245124/can-too-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination)

It looks like the restriction is for *just* the nomination phase. However, we will not have a primary (unless more than 7 candidates step forwards this afternoon), and I think comments disappear during the voting phase.

Comment: That is incredibly stupid.  I hope they fix that soon.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer well, you might want to file a [meta-tag:feature-request] here or on MSE then

Comment: Figured there would already be one, but NOPE.  Here's a link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253297/let-us-upvote-or-at-least-flag-comments-in-the-nomination-phase-of-electio

Comment: @thedarkwanderer that's...not going to go well. MSE is a very different place from a per site meta, that kind of tone may well get you downvoted to oblivion there. Or just quickly duped...

Comment: Yah, that's my first post there.  I've avoided it in the past because I do not understand it yet.  I have much trouble in these kinds of things (I had to stalk this site for about a year before I could really join) so I expect both and at least one person telling me I'm insane.  I can't really do any better though.  Feel free to suggest or make edits! (or just post your own thing if you agree with the feature request, that might go better than me stumbling around with my foot in my mouth)